# Sorting a list inside dictionary keys - Highest score from a list of 3

Tags: python, dictionary

I have asked a similar question like this before, so I do apologise, but I read the task back and had misread the original requirements.

So, based on the feedback that I received here, this is the code that I used:

```
def task3():
    classList = {}
    classSearch = input("Which class would you like to interrogate? ")
    try:
        with open("answers " + classSearch + ".txt", 'rb') as handle:
            classList = pickle.loads(handle.read())
    except IOError as error:
        print ("Sorry, this file does not exist")

    sortOption = int(input("Would you like sort the students in alphabetical order? Enter 1\n Would you like to sort the students by highest score? Enter 2 \nWould you like to sort students by their average score?Enter 3\n"))
    if sortOption == 1:
        x = sorted(classList.items())
        for key, value in x:
            value.sort()
            value.reverse()
        print (x)
```

So what I actually need to do is to output the highest score of each student, sorted alphabetically by name. Inside the classList dictionary is a students name and then a list containing the last 3 scores that they received on the quiz. This is obviously repeated for multiple students.  Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: A standard dictionary is unordered. That means that you can't sort it. I think you'll need a ordereddict. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it myself in the end by printing the index position 0

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, assuming the inputs are completely unsorted:

```
for name,highscore in [(student,max(classList[student])) for student in sorted(classList.keys())]:
    print name,highscore
```

**ETA**:

As requested, providing an explanation.

classList is a `dict`, with each member consisting of a key (student's name) and a value (list of scores for that student).

My suggested code iterates over a pre-sorted list comprehension of tuples containing the student name and highest score for that student, printing each in turn.

The list comprehension does all the work here.

`classList.keys()` produces a list containing the student names. The built-in `sorted` function returns the same sorted in alphabetical order, in this case.

The list comprehension is like a for loop, iterating over the list of keys, and building a list of tuples.

You could also have said

```
sortedNames = sorted(classList.keys())
for student in sortedNames:
    high_score = max(classList[student])
    print student, high_score
```

Comment: Hi, I'm in a similar situation to the OP. This code worked for me. Could you please explain it, because I don't understand it?

Comment: Also, which of those are variables? Is student a variable? If not, what is it?

Comment: @Kaiylar, variables is a bit of a misnomer, I think it's labels for Python?

Comment: I haven't heard of the term 'label' before. So what does `student` actually act as? How does the program know that you're referring to keys when you type `student`?

Comment: Could you please suggest how you would do this same sort of thing but instead of sorting the highest score of each student alphabetically their names, each student's highest score would be sorted from the highest score to the lowest?

Comment: I have this code for it: http://prntscr.com/b6ppu7 It works, but it outputs: http://prntscr.com/b6pq3j I instead want it to output each student's name and highest score below each other (in a list-like format), similar to how your code for the alphabetical sorting outputs it.